# Positionning the root of some TikZ tree in text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to position the root of a tree into some (mathematical) text.

Concretely, my code looks like this MWE:

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\BT}[1]{\mathrm{BT}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document} %----------------------------------------

\[ \BT{M} := \lambda x_1.\dots\lambda x_n.
\tikz[level distance=1.5cm,baseline]{
\node {$y$}
    child { node {$\BT{M_1}$} }
    child { node {\dots{}} edge from parent[draw=none] }
    child { node {$\BT{M_p}$} }
; } \]

\end{document}
```

and renders this:

[image]

whereas I would like something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this (if possible without ugly manual spacing)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: Done! Sorry for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\BT}[1]{\mathrm{BT}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document} 
\[ 
\tikz[node distance=0pt,
      level distance=1.5cm,baseline]
{
\node (n) {$\vphantom{\lambda)}y$}
    child { node {$\BT{M_1}$} }
    child { node {\dots} edge from parent[draw=none] }
    child { node {$\BT{M_p}$} }; 
\node[left=of n,inner xsep=-2pt] {$\BT{M} := \lambda x_1\dots\lambda x_n.$};
} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**  The first sugestion cna be simplified by use of the `tikzmark`. Since it use `overlay` and `remember picture` options, it need to be compiled (at least) twice that the showed result is achieved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\BT}[1]{\mathrm{BT}\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}
\[
\BT{M} := \lambda x_1\dots\lambda x_n.\tikzmarknode{a}{y}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
                        level distance=12mm, sibling distance=11mm]
\node at (a.south) {}
    child { node {$\BT{M_1}$} }
    child { node {\dots} edge from parent[draw=none] }
    child { node {$\BT{M_p}$} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've taken the liberty of suggesting an edit with reversed dependencies between nodes (using `right=of n` instead of `left`), which facilitates nesting trees (I need to do this in practice).

Comment: However, isn't there a way to avoid using `\vphantom` and to vertically align nodes on each other's baseline?

Comment: @sparusaurata, your question is different. what you add to my answer, can be solved on different way. I will show this late evening.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I added a bad suggestion @Zarko, thanks for offer your help!

Comment: @sparusaurata, I added new solution for your problem described in question. Also I remove your edit since it is out of your question (as I already mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: Thanks! (I had to use a more recent version of `tikzmark` than the one in my TeXlive, but it works perfectly.) The code looks much prettier indeed. However I don't see how this facilitates nesting the trees, as I wood like to.

Comment: @sparusaurata, this is new question. Pleas ask it as such. Here is not visible to the other people who may help you.